# Can not wrap my middle 100% width div with 2 divs with a fixed width

Tags: html, css

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/AHdLm

I have 3 divs:

A left and right div with a fixed width of 40px; (red colored)
Between is a middle div with a fluid width of 100%;

Of course 40px + 100% + 40px will always wrap the divs just like it is now.

I can not use position:fixed for a solution and I need it for IE8+.

How can I achieve that?

**HTML**

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div style="float:left;width:40px;height:80px;background:red;">Left</div>
            <div style="float:left;" class="table">
                <div id="navBar" >
                    <div class="cellContainer">
                        <div class="template">11</div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="cellContainer">
                        <div class="template">22</div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="cellContainer">
                        <div class="template">33</div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="cellContainer">
                        <div class="template">44</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     <div style="float:left;width:40px;height:80px;background:red;">Right</div> 
    <div style="clear:both" />
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cellContainer {
    width: 20%;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;   
}

.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: orange;
}

.template{
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: lightgray;
    border: black solid 1px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#navBar {
    border: black solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Why the right div is made `float: left`?

Comment: Cant you use width of the blocks in left end and the right end in percentage ? Or you want it to be in pixels, then why so ?

Comment: sorry forget about the float:left on all 3 divs.

Comment: No I can not use percentage I need to have it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="float:left;width:40px;height:80px;background:red;margin-left:-40px;">Left</div>
            <div style="float:left; width:100%;background:blue;" class="table">
                <div id="navBar" >
                    <div class="cellContainer">
                        <div class="template">11</div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="cellContainer">
                        <div class="template">22</div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="cellContainer">
                        <div class="template">33</div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="cellContainer">
                        <div class="template">44</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     <div style="float:right;width:40px;height:80px;background:red; margin-right:-40px;">Right</div> 
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {padding:0 40px;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqM5k/)

however the above will not keep your columns the same height.  If you want to do this you can go the `display:table` route (but this isn't compatible with earlier versions of ie):

[Display table](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqM5k/1/)

Comment: IE8+ is fine see my init question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css for .table

```
.table {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

and use `float: right;` for the right div.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bspdn

Comment: I would have to comment that if there is any html below the wrapper div and the table div expands, this solution will not work as the absolutely positioned div will not push the lower down but just overlap it